# Correct way of rewriting `curl ...` to perl

Tags: perl, curl, http-headers

I wrote a program that requests the source and the response header of a webpage, now I need it to run cross platform. I used the external command curl (in linux) to achieve it. I get the source like this::

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

#declaring variables here#

my $result = `curl 'https://$host$request' -H 'Host: $host' -H 'User-Agent: $useragent' -H 'Accept: $accept' -H 'Accept-Language: $acceptlanguage' --compressed -H 'Cookie: $cookie' -H 'DNT: $dnt' -H 'Connection: $connection' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: $upgradeinsecure' -H 'Cache-Control: $cachecontrol'`;
print "$result\n";
```

And the response header like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

#declaring variables here#

my $result = `curl -I 'https://$host$request' -H 'Host: $host' -H 'User-Agent: $useragent' -H 'Accept: $accept' -H 'Accept-Language: $acceptlanguage' --compressed -H 'Cookie: $cookie' -H 'DNT: $dnt' -H 'Connection: $connection' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: $upgradeinsecure' -H 'Cache-Control: $cachecontrol'`;
print "$result\n";
```

These work fine, but I need to call these in perl and not as external commands.
I wrote some code using `LWP::UserAgent` to get the source:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

#declaring variables here#

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "https://$host$request HTTP/1.1");
$req->header('Host' => "$host");
$req->header('User-Agent' => "$useragent");
$req->header('Accept' => "$accept");
$req->header('Accept-Language' => "$acceptlanguage");
$req->header('Accept-Encoding' => "$acceptencoding");
$req->header('Cookie' => "$cookie");
$req->header('DNT' => "$dnt");
$req->header('Connection' => "$connection");
$req->header('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => "$upgradeinsecure");
$req->header('Cache-Control' => "$cachecontrol");

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "$message\n";
}
```

This sometimes runs fine, but sometimes `decoded_content` returns nothing, I do get a response and i can print it using `content`, but its still encoded.

And requesting response headers using `LWP::UserAgent` is not possible so I wrote the request using `Net::HTTP`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Net::HTTP;

#declaring variables here#

my $s = Net::HTTP->new(Host => "$host") || die $@;
$s->write_request(GET => "$request", 'Host' => "$host", 'User-Agent' => "$useragent", 'Accept' => "$accept", 'Accept-Language' => "$acceptlanguage", 'Accept-Encoding' => "$acceptencoding", 'Cookie' => "$cookie", 'DNT' => "$dnt", 'Connection' => "$connection", 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => "$upgradeinsecure", 'Cache-Control' => "$cachecontrol");

my @headers;

while(my $line = <$s>) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    push @headers, $line;
}
print @headers;
```

This returns

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Is the problem with my syntax of am I using the wrong tools? I know that `WWW::Curl::Easy` can request the source and the header at the same time, but I don't know how to pass my variables to its request. Could someone tell me what the problem is or just rewrite these requests correctly using the same variables with `WWW:Curl::Easy`? I'd appreciate a solution using `WWW::Curl::Easy`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "requesting headers using `LWP::UserAgent` is not possible" -- er, what?? Read the documentation. `$resp->header("Content-Type")`, etc.

Comment: print <$s>; and it should be obvious.

Comment: @Сухой27 `print Dumper($s);` returns `$VAR1 = bless( \*Symbol::GEN0, 'Net::HTTP' );`,  `print $s;` returns `Net::HTTP=GLOB(0xddd9f8)` and `print <$s>;` returns empty string, so I am not sure what you meant.

Comment: `302` should be redirect to another url. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302#Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the response headers in a couple of ways with LWP. Demonstrated here:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my($host,$request) = ('example.com', '/my/request');
my @header=( [Host         => $host],
             ['User-Agent' => 'James Bond 2.0'],
             [Accept       => 'text/plain'],
             [Cookie       => 'cookie=x'],
           );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "https://$host$request");  #dont add HTTP/1.1
$req->header(@$_) for @header;
my $resp = $ua->request($req);

if ($resp->is_success) {

    my %h; $resp->headers->scan( sub{ $h{shift()}=shift() } );
    printf "Header name: %-30s  Value: %-30s\n", $_, $h{$_} for sort keys %h;

    print "\n<<<".$resp->headers()->as_string.">>>\n\n"; #all header lines in one big string

    print $resp->header('Content-Type'),"\n\n";  #get one specific header line

    my $content = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "$content\n";
}
```

Note: "HTTP/1.1" should not be a part of the string after `GET =>`.

And with calling `curl` as a sub process you don't need to call it twice. You can get both headers and content at once by using `-i` like this:

```
my $response = ` curl -s -i "http://somewhere.com/path" -H 'User-Agent: Yes' `;
my($headers,$content) = split /\cM?\cJ\cM?\cJ/, $response, 2;
print "Headers: <<<$headers>>>\n\n";
print "Content: <<<$content>>>\n\n";
```

Comment: This works fine, it doesn't give the same result, but I can use it, except for when the page I request doesn't contain anything, it is only supposed to return a redirection link in the header but `is_success` returns 1. And btw. my code runs fine is I leave the `accept-encoding` part out.

Comment: If I request the Header using `curl`, it returns `HTTP/2 302` and a proper redirection link, if I request it using `Net::HTTP` it returns `HTTP/1.1 302` and the link I requested, as the redirection link, and your method returns `Error: 404 Not Found` Any idea what causes that?